# sauce labs load timeout for modules

Tags: intern

I am running client unit tests in intern using phantomjs in one grunt task and a selenium server in another grunt task locally without any issues. However, when I bring sauce labs into mix during CI and attempt to dynamically load a module during a test I receive a load modules error as seen in the "Failing CI job" link below. All other modules load as expected, which doesn't make sense because they share the same requirejs loader instance with the same `baseUrl`. If I remove tests that dynamically load modules then there are not any errors.

- [Failing CI job](https://travis-ci.org/lazojs/lazo/builds/49250655)
- [Failing test](https://github.com/lazojs/lazo/blob/v2/test/unit/client-server/public/views/base.js#L137)
- [Dynamic load in source](https://github.com/lazojs/lazo/blob/v2/lib/public/views/view.js#L143)

Answer (score 0):

Magically passed, https://travis-ci.org/lazojs/lazo/builds/49259156. More words to meet minimum answer length requirement.